# Debezium connector for PostgreSQL Connector configuration is invalid

Tags: postgresql, debezium

I have trouble with configuring debezium connector for PostgreSQL in Windows 10. My config:

```
"{\"name\":\"sde-connector\", \"config\":
{\"connector.class\":\"io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector\", 
\"database.hostname\":\"10.80.244.128\", \"database.port\":\"6432\", 
\"database.user\":\"postgres\", \"database.password\":\"123456\", 
\"database.dbname\":\"postgres\", \"table.include.list\":\"bank.holding\",
 \"topic.prefix\":\"test_topic\", \"table.whitelist\": \"bank.holding\",
 \"signal.kafka.bootstrap.servers\":\"kafka:9092\"}}"
```

I get an error:

```
{"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 
error(s):\nA value is required\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint 
`/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}
```

I checked the docs about debezium for postgres but didn't find what extra mandatory parameters I should pass to config.

I use `debezium/connect:1.1` docker image.

Curl command to register debezium connect

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-
Type:application/json" -d "{\"name\":\"sde-connector\", \"config\":
{\"connector.class\":\"io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector\",
 \"database.hostname\":\"10.80.244.128\", \"database.port\":\"6432\", 
\"database.user\":\"postgres\", \"database.password\":\"123456\", 
\"database.dbname\":\"postgres\", \"table.include.list\":\"bank.holding\",
 \"topic.prefix\":\"test_topic\", \"table.whitelist\": \"bank.holding\",
 \"signal.kafka.bootstrap.servers\":\"kafka:9092\"}}"
 localhost:8083/connectors
```